# Printing NPAPI plugin at high DPI

Tags: firefox, printing, gdi, npapi

I'm trying to print an NPAPI plugin from Firefox, but facilities for doing so seem to be lacking.  The NPPrint event gives me a device context but this only ever seems to print at about 150 DPI, no matter what scale factor I set the mapping mode to.  For printing text (the purpose of this plugin) the results are unacceptably "chunky".

The plugin doesn't appear at all when I print preview the document- though nor do Java or Flash plugins, making me think this is by design.

Question 1- am I missing something and there is actually a way to make the supplied DC print at 300+ DPI?  I tried MM_ISOTROPIC with viewport extents 3 times greater than the window extents; should I be using MM_TWIPS or MM_HIENGLISH instead?

Question 2- is there any way at all to make an NPAPI plugin draw to a print preview?

Comment: I wish I knew; I'd love to add support for printing to FireBreath (http://www.firebreath.org) but I have never needed it.  I'm also hoping for an answer to this question.